# AS3 can't delete element from array with splice()

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I have a class called BouncingEnemy that extends sprite.
In its constructor I call `level.enemies.push(this); //(level.enemies is an array)`
When I test collisions I loop through each enemy with

```
for each (var en:BouncingEnemy in level.enemies) {
    if (!(en === this)) {
        //code to test collisions
    }
}
```

When the enemy gets killed, I call

```
level.enemies.splice(level.enemies.indexOf(this), 1);
level.removeChild (this);
```

My problem is that when I execute the last snippet of code, the enemy does disappear from screen, but the other enemies will still collide against it as if it was still there. What's wrong with my code?

---

EDIT: Note that all the code above is inside the BouncingEnemy class. When I loop through level.enemies from any other class, everything goes as expected.

---

When i commented out the `level.removeChild (this);` line, I also noticed that "deleted" enemies do not collide against each other. They only collide against walls (which are tested separately) and "real" enemies.

---

The problem remains even after I made Level.enemies static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For speed optimisation you should use :

```
var t:int = int(level.enemies.length);
for(var i:uint = 0; i < t; i++){
    if(level.enemies[i] !== this){
        //test collision
        //if collision and if enemy dies ? not sure about how your code is organized
        level.removeChild(level.enemies[i]);
        level.enemies.splice(i, 1);            
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you can even use Dictionary() instead of array which is even faster if you want to stick to for each.

Comment: 1)Enemies are not killed when they collide, they bounce when they collide, and they are killed when their HP reach 0
2)Speed optimisation is not what I asked for, but since I'm desperate I will try to use for instead of for each and see if that works.

Comment: Is there any listener binded to any of your enemies? I usually remove the listeners before deleting the object to make sure no reference is left.

Comment: Yes, indeed! There was an ENTER_FRAME event listener. Which kept being fired even after the code to kill the enemy had been called, thus triggering the collision... so the problem was not that real enemies collided with dead ones, but that dead enemies kept looking for collisions even after being killed (only with real enemies, which is why dead enemies didn't collide with each other).